# How to add on my image gif's watermark with php?

Tags: php, image, gif, watermark, shell-exec

I try this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path));

$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);

$centerX=round($w/4);
$centerY=round($h/2);

$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('lool-face.png');
$ww = imagesx($watermark);
$wh = imagesy($watermark);

imagecopy($image, $watermark, $centerX, $centerY, 0, 0, $ww, $wh);

eregi('\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$',$path,$regs);
switch( $regs[1] ) {
case 'gif':
   header('Content-type: image/gif');
   imagegif($image);
   break;
```

but this don't working, the images is curdle.

And try this:

```
shell_exec('for i in sphere*.gif; do convert $i  -font Arial -pointsize 20 \
    -draw "gravity south \
    fill black  text 0,12 \'Copyright\' \
    fill white  text 1,11 \'Copyright\' " \
    wmark_$i; done');

shell_exec("convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   wmark_sphere*.gif   animatespheres.gif");
$f = fopen("animatespheres.gif", 'rb');
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
```

This code does not work I do not know why it does not.
We wish you a directory where there Gif htaccess can do it in gifs watermarking

Answer (score 1):

This class could be your solution:
[PHP Classes transparent watermark](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1580-PHP-Apply-a-transparent-watermark-to-protect-images.html)

Comment: I remember experimenting with animated GIF overlaying and I spent ages and ages because animation breaks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link below. I have done the same thing in php. I hope that this will helps you.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58146160/watermark%20image.rar

Comment: To make it working with gifs you have to change the code a little bit in funs.php